# GMtool and Jenkins - Android devices disappear as soon as "gmtool admin start $devicename" finishes

Tags: jenkins, genymotion

I'm trying to start a device using Genymotion GMTool from Jenkins by executing a batch command: "gmtool admin start $devicename" and the device does start

The problem is that as soon as the build ends, the device disappears from the screen copletely though is still visible in ADB.

Also, if i execute the same gmtool command from the windows cli the device stays on the screen.

Anyone knows what may cause this issue?

Comment: Do you do a "gmtool admin stop" at the end of your tests ?

Comment: Does your windows is the Jenkins server or a slave?

Comment: @eyal-lezmy I'm not using "gmtool admin stop" since i want the devices to remain open, also i'm running the commands on the slave

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe because Jenkins process will kill all its childs and also the Genymotion device window running after the slave's job finished. But the problem here is that your Genymotion device is composed by a window (called "player") displaying the device and a headless virtual box process running the Android OS (including the ADB deamon).

If the device player is hardly killed, the vbox process will not be powered off at the same time. That's the reason why you still see the device connected to adb. 
You can check this idea is true by checking on your running processes if you have a vbox headless process remaining after the window disappeared.

The solution could be:

- to use another way to launch your devices (with a cron task for example).
- to check if it is possible to set something on Jenkins to avoid this problem
- to start a new device for each test run